# Apply a reputation loss for posting the 1st comment at any post

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, comments

There's a lot of complaint recently, about the culture of Stack Exchange sites, and how newcomers feel unwelcomed, or just feel being minorized when asking questions.

One source of these complaints are snarky and unnecessary comments placed on posts (no matter which quality they actually are):

> *"Do your homework please!"*
>
> ---
>
> *"What did you try?"*
>
> ---
>
> *"Here's what I found at google as the 1st hits: "*
>
> ---
>
> *"What on earth are you talking about?"*

All of the above examples are already addressed well (doesn't mean there could not be improvement regarding tooltips, auto notifiers and on hold/closed banners), and that kind of comments just tend to make new users upset about the commentator and start biased and off-topic discussions.

I believe that applying a small reputation cost (similar as for downvoting answers) of -1 or -2 for the 1st comment written at any post (be it question or answer), could radically help to reduce that kind of mostly useless (and unconstructive) noise.

That would also encourage users to think twice, and either to write a comment with that initial cost, or an answer which has a chance to start with 0 cost and getting upvoted.

There are already reasons why comments containing the key acronyms RTFM<sup>1</sup> or LMGTFY<sup>2</sup> are considered rude and unconstructive.

While could be considered as helpful to some degree, these will leave OPs with a belittled and blamed themselves in the public feeling.

That's just not necessary, we have better tools to teach new users. Those ones who don't care to read further, will be lost anywhere anyways.

Duplicate (auto comments) must be handled as a special use case, and either be refunded as accepted, or at least left neutral against reputation.

I'd like to hear what pros and cons you otherwise could see for such feature.

---

#### For the record:

It is quite interesting to see by the scores of this FR discussion, how hard some people are defending to keep their gameified internet reputation points over a possible regulation (i.e.: just to give something away in the game, getting trustfully social, pay for attention, show your responsibility), whatever it be.

If I can't be convinced that the community here is able to do better into that direction, instead of not just going into charge by thinking from the other points view, this is probably not the place anymore I thought I've been joining once.

---

#### One of my prejudicable ...

(that's probably a word invented by myself) ... statements is according to *Groucho Marx'* great statement:

> > *"I don't care to belong to any club that will have me as a member."*

I'd probably better stick to that.

---

Driving and teaching new users to post better quality questions shouldn't be left to commentators, also the close vote mechanics need to hit OPs at a certain threshold, and need to be more thoroughly explained.

I am already bothered (and I believe I am not the only one) for looking like an ice cold robot for this.

I don't want to loose the transparency carried on with close votes, though also made proposals to anonymize and improve this (see a FR [here](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/wouldnt-it-be-more-useful-to-notify-ops-automatically-about-close-votes-instea)), and also asked about [clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222473/in-which-way-the-op-is-notified-about-close-votes) earlier.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>**R**ead **T**he **F**ine **M**anuals</sub>
<sup>2)</sup><sub>**L**ook **M**y **G**oogle query **T**ook it for a **F**airly good **Y**ield</sub>

Comment: It would also penalize people who post helpful comments, like "Can you please also include how the variables are declared?".

Comment: @PeterJ What makes you think that reputation loss/giveaway is _penalizing_? It's a tweak in the game, and merely tells you from the beginning: _"Take care what you're saying, and how."_. This is a gamification driven website, don't forget that before getting lost please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: A reputation penalty was added to downvoting answers to make sure that if you're going to downvote an answer, you should really mean it. If I'm asking someone for more information for their not-clear post, I don't *really* care that much. I've already voted to close it; asking for information is just a courtesy. I'm going to be a lot less courteous if it costs me something.

Comment: @nicol While I see your point, just commenting, just even asking for clarification already seems to defeat some users. May it be cultural or personal reasons. It doesn't matter, you should be _in charge_ and conscious about it when writing comments. There could be all kinds of rep loss refund mechanisms. The _"Question was edited and improved as suggested in comment"_ gold badge, whatever.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "*just commenting, just even asking for clarification already seems to defeat some users*" If they're "defeated" by commenting, no matter how "welcoming" it may be, then how will *not* commenting be better for them? Because that's just going to get their question closed without someone saying why. I can't imagine such people feeling that this is a better experience.

Comment: @Nicol _"Because that's just going to get their question closed without someone saying why. "_ See here please: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6907366#6907366

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "Your post is unclear" is not much of a "reason". If they thought their post was unclear, they wouldn't have asked it. Without guidance as to what's unclear about it, there's nothing to be done. Furthermore, without a comment, you can't fix the problem *before it's closed*, which frequently happens in tags that aren't getting 30 questions a second.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: There are far more effective ways of [improving the comment system without rate limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140693/making-the-comment-system-better).

Comment: @Nicol I've already been asking for another FR to make low rep users aware of close votes/flags beyond a certain threshold. Was as well declined. I believe we have to take that burden and give away some internet reputation points freely to show everyone we really mean it, and don't do it only for _our ego_ / _presence_ / _rep farming_ / _stalking_ / <place your arbitrary reason>, but really giving away something that makes us more trustful in our willingness to help and improve quality.

Comment: @DVer's Good dupe anyone?

Comment: I agree with your description of the problem.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think the downvoters are downvoting because it's just a bad idea with no real upside.

Comment: @AndrewLi There is no reason to be downvoting this question. I see it as evidence that there is a problem with the comment section.

Comment: @FrankHubeny It's a feature request. Voting indicates agreement with the feature request itself.

Comment: @AndrewLi This is a question seeking answers--pros and cons. Answers should be made, not downvotes for asking the question.

Comment: @FrankHubeny A feature request that's posted inherently 'asks' for pros and cons for feedback. Voting explicitly is used to gauge the community's reaction to the request itself. What πάντα is suggesting is invasive to a vital part of the community the SO management seem to be all to eager to dismantle—quality control. Sure, these comments are snarky sometimes, but what about the actual helpful comments? It generalized every single commenter under single identity, something SO management is trying so hard not to do ironically.

Comment: @AndrewLi Again, this is a question looking for answers.  The question is a good one and the use of downvoting as it is being used here discourages anyone posting unpopular questions. This particular example is a good reason to remove the ability to downvote at all.

Comment: @FrankHubeny So we should get rid *of any feedback mechanism towards feature requests*?! It's unpopular for a reason. There is no question other than the implicit question of "is this a good feature request" presented by every single feature request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1184/discussion-between-frank-hubeny-and-andrew-li).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So everytime I choose a reason, in the review queue instead of choosing the option that doesn't result in an automatic comment being submitted, you propose I should lose reputation?  If there was an easy way to pull new users into a chatroom, comments would be used less, but chat requires more reputation then most users have (especially if they have already asked a low-quality question)

Comment: @FrankHubeny - Voting is the only way I can idicate I agree or disagree with a dicussion and/or feature request here at meta other then submitting an answser which repeats what somebody already said.

Comment: @Ramhound There is a chat area open on this. Voting is not the only way. You can post a comment and even better you can answer the question which is asking for pros and cons. There is nothing wrong with this question except that it is unpopular. Based on the response to this question, I am in favor of removing the ability to downvote.

Comment: @FrankHubeny - Everyone is always so concerned with downvotes but nobody ever talks about all the upvotes that are issued, without a single explanation.  I have literally seen comments (i.e. "Thanks for the help" type statements), submitted as an answer, that received multiple upvotes from users.

Answer (score 27):

Two cons come to mind pretty quickly:

- **It disincentivizes people from posting helpful comments early on.** If you're writing a good comment to ask for clarification or improve a post, you're already being a bit altruistic. To penalize people for that seems . . . slightly unjust. Some people are helpful; let's not be hard on them. I suppose that it's akin to losing one rep point for downvoting, which isn't too bad, but there are many people - especially on smaller sites - who routinely post helpful stuff as soon as they see a question, and this sort of rep loss would build up for them.
- **After the first comment, it doesn't do anything.** Okay, so one person posts a comment, be it good or bad. Now everyone else can post more comments - helpful or not - without any reputation loss, and there's nothing to stop more unnecessary comments from pouring in. I don't have data hear, but I'd guess that most posts that receive at least one comment receive more than just one.

Maybe a way of getting around the first issue would be to apply rep penalties for writing a whole bunch of flaggable (read: unnecessary, snarky, etc.) comments, but after a point, a user may get suspended for long-term patterns of problematic comment behavior.

Comment: 1. _**It disincentivizes people from posting helpful comments early on.** Yes, and it's unintentional. TBF none of my examples mentioned what could be considered a _good comment_. 2. Shog9 offered another way to go: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6907703#6907703

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yeah, Shog's idea isn't better. At the end of the day, it still leaves tons of questions left closed with nobody explaining why outside of a canned response. These are really "baby with the bathwater" kinds of ideas.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - I have found when people, believe they have to clarify a statement with "no offense", they already realize that their statement can be read as offensive. **I typically find somebody telling me I don't understand something, to be offensive, and normally just flag the comment as rude.**